# Regexp to search for strings like 'cpt' => on Notepad++

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to build a list of array of mime types for PHP. I got a long list of mime types but I need to remove all the `'xxx' =>` upfront. How to detect them using regexp cos I tried `'[\u][a-z0-9]' =>`  and it didn't work.

```
    'cpt' => 'application/mac-compactpro',
    'cpt' => 'application/x-compactpro',
    'cpt' => 'application/x-cpt',
    'crl' => 'application/pkcs-crl',
    'crl' => 'application/pkix-crl',
    'crt' => 'application/pkix-cert',
    'crt' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'crt' => 'application/x-x509-user-cert',
    'csh' => 'application/x-csh',
    'csh' => 'text/x-script.csh',
    'css' => 'application/x-pointplus',
```

Comment: Or try  `^[\s]+'[a-z]+' => `  will also detect your desired text,  you must to use `^`  which means from the start of every line ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  ....
Find:`^\s*'\w+' =>` 
Replace with:`empty`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^\s*'.*?'\s*=>\s*('.*?',?)$
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple. You need to search for `^\s*'\w\w\w' =>`

Don't forget to set the Search Mode to `Regular Expression` in the search dialog.